# Laravel 8: controller refactoring, consolidate store() and create() functions?

Tags: php, laravel, solid-principles

I have a function `create()` which returns the `view` of the insert form:

```
    /**
     ** Add new Record Page.
     **/
    public function create()
    {
        $locationList = Locations::all(); // This is fetching data from another table to use in a <select>
        return view('pages.dataEntry.lostFound._addForm', compact('locationList'));
    }
```

And another function `store()` for creating the new record. I created a request file to shorten the `store()` in the controller:

```
    /**
     ** Add new Record.
     **/
    public function store(LostFoundRequest $request)
    {
        $lostFound = LostFound::create( $request->validated() );

        $request->store();
        return redirect()->route('data-entry.lost-and-found.index')
            ->with('success', 'LF Added Successfully');

    }
```

I want to get rid of the `create()`. Is it possible to `return view` of the form? `$request->store` then after submitting `return redirect()` in one function?

Is there a better/cleaner way for doing this? 
Or am I following the **SOLID** principle correctly? "**S:** Single responsibility" per function?

Comment: I don't see a reason why you would want to do that. `create()` has the single purpose of displaying a form, `store()` has the single purpose of storing data

Comment: So I'm doing a good practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify controllers for simple crud by passing a new (unsaved) model into the other controller methods.

eg;

```php
public function create()
{
    return $this->edit(new Post());
}

public function store(PostForm $request)
{
    return $this->update($request, new Post());
}

public function edit(Post $post)
{
    return view('post.edit', compact('post'));
}

public function update(postForm $request, post $post)
{
    //store post

    return redirect(route('posts.index'));
}
```

When you couple this with route model binding, you get a very simple controller.  One view for the form for both create and update.  The `create` method uses the `edit` method, passing it an empty model, and `store` uses the `update` method, again passing it an empty model.

The form opening tag needs to be different which can be solved with a simple blade `@if`

```html
@if($post->exists)
    <form class="flex flex-col w-full" method="POST" action="{{ route('posts.update',$post) }}">
        @method('put')
@else
    <form class="flex flex-col w-full" method="POST" action="{{ route('posts.store') }}">
@endif
```

The `->exists` returns a boolean to tell us if the model has been persisted.  If not then this is a create form, otherwise its an edit form.

From my article https://talltips.novate.co.uk/laravel/simplify-laravel-crud-controllers